# configuration for maximum response size for apache

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there a config setting in apache that can limit the size (or maybe limits the maximum size) of a response?

I'm working on an embedded device that uses apache server to host its web interface. The JavaScript uses AJAX to pull data from our device. We sometimes encounter a situation in which the AJAX response is larger than 512MB (that size may be wrong -- it's been a long time since we first identified the problem). When this happens the client receives an incomplete response.

I'm looking at re-writing the AJAX communication to reduce the scope of the logical data requests so that the responses will be smaller. But it would be good to know why we're seeing this response size limit in the first place.

UPDATE

FYI to anyone who stumbles on this in the future: I discovered the root cause of this error was not apache, but a hard memory limit (because it's running in an embedded environment) within the process that generates the AJAX response string.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you are seeing?

Comment: Are you sure, that this is an Apache problem and not a crash of your CGI script? See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html for reference on how to debug errors with CGI script.

Comment: yes, I gnerate a zip of 1.5gb and this solution works. It works icreasing memory of php, in php.ini set memory_limit = 2000M